# SwiftUI: On tap gesture switches views

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-ontapgesture

I have the following simplified code in a project using XCode 13.2. The intended functionality is to have 2 tabs (`Tab1` and `Tab2`), and the user is able to tap the screen on `Tab2` to toggle the background from red to green.

Instead, however, when `Tab2` is clicked, the screen displays tab 1, instead of `Tab2` with the changed color. I'm wondering why the app goes to `Tab1` when `Tab2` is tapped.

There are no NavigationLinks or actions that make the user go to `Tab1`. My only thought is that maybe the app is rebuilding when `Tab2` is clicked, which is why it goes back to the first tab? If so, are there any good workarounds for this?

**Note**: the color still changes on `Tab2`, but not before the app switches to `Tab1`.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView {
            Tab1()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 1")
                }
            Tab2()
                .tabItem {
                    Text("Tab 2")
                }
        }
    }
}

struct Tab1: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tab 1")
    }
}

struct Tab2: View {
    @State var isRed: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if !isRed {
            Color.green
                .onTapGesture {
                    isRed = true
                }
        } else {
            Color.red
                .onTapGesture {
                    isRed = false
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why tapping on Tab2 causes it to jump back to Tab1 is that the structural identity of Tab2 changes whenever you tap on it causing swiftUI to reload the body. See the explanation [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/).
A simple fix to the example you have above would be to wrap the entire body in a `ZStack`

```
var body: some View {
  ZStack {
    if !isRed {
      Color.green
        .onTapGesture {
          isRed = true
        }
    } else {
      Color.red
        .onTapGesture {
          isRed = false
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that using if/else in that way causes strange behavior. Refactor Tab2 as shown below and it should work as expected.

```
struct Tab2: View {
@State var isRed: Bool = false

var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        Color.green
            .opacity(isRed ? 0 : 1)
    }
    .onTapGesture {
        isRed.toggle()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This worked, thanks! If you find out why this happens, let us know!

Comment: @purpleprince if this answer worked, you should mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Anwuna I was going to keep it un-accepted, just because I was wondering whats actually happening and why the issue was occurring. The workaround was helpful though, so should I still mark it as accepted?

Comment: If you haven't found an acceptable answer, then I think upvoting David's answer is good enough.